# Encrypted text is too large in AES algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, cryptography, aes

Am using the below AES algorithm code to encrypt the given text.

```
string EncryptionKey = "abc";
string originalText = "Original text";
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(originalText);
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }

                string encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

Output:

> XBqY9wBUpAa+ly7P2cdZBQ==

If i increase the characters of the original text, then the encrypted text size also increasing.

For Example:

**Input:**

> original text is length is increased

**Output:**

> RU3azV4sslgUWFSoCKxdKHN/qDCEcKXN/tCFa80Bcmu1O418T/CGRZc3mIzx0f2Q

The result string should not increase based on the input text. How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, what you're asking is impossible.

I'm no cryptography expert, but I'll try to explain the best I can:

Let `e(x)` be a function that encrypts a given x

Let `d(x)` be a function that decrypts a given x

Let x be some string.

Just think about this for a second. If e(x) takes x and encrypts it, then there must exist a d(x) that will decrypt our ciphertext and give us our original text back. Otherwise, our encryption algorithm is useless! If the size of the result of e(x) could not change, then it would be impossible for d(x) to exist. This is because there is only so much data that can be encoded in text (127 possible values per byte in ascii). So naturally, as the size of the input message to e(x) grows, the size of some cipher text (the result of e(x)) will also grow at similar rate.

If you want to reduce the size of the output text, you can look into using compression. I don't have much experience in this personally, but you may want to look into something like [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, as Luke suggested, you may be looking for a hashing algorithm, which will make your text a fixed size. For c#, maybe look into [HashAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The OP probably just wants a hashing algorithm and doesnt know the right words to explain what he wants.

Comment: "*although it will still grow as your input text grows, for the same reasons I gave above*" -- 
Hashing algorithms **don't** grow as the input text grows. It has fixed length output.

Comment: If you want to encrypt something without increasing its size, you will have to use one-time padding.  :3  But then your problem becomes how do you share the encrypt key with the intended parties.

Comment: @luke I tried hashing. it reduced the size of encrypted text. But this too grows as per the input text grows

Comment: @Kathir You are mistaken. Hashing is not encryption. Hash is a one-way function, data are destroyed in the process, you can never turn the hash back into original data. Hash output is fixed size, according to the hashing algorithm used. If your output grows you are doing something wrong.